# Recursive function with template parameter pack keeps calling itself even though there is an overload with an end condition

Tags: c++, templates

I was trying to write my own tuple, and wrote the code below:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Holder{
    T elem;
};

template<typename firstType, typename ...types>
struct scatter : public Holder<firstType>{};

template<typename firstType,typename ...types>
struct myTuple: public scatter<firstType,types...>,public myTuple<types...>{};

template<typename firstType>
struct myTuple<firstType> : public scatter<firstType>{};

template<int>
struct IntToType{};

/* these work ok */
template<typename firstType,typename ...types>
auto getHelper(myTuple<firstType,types...> &tupleObj,IntToType<0>)
-> decltype((tupleObj.scatter<firstType,types...>::elem))
{
    return tupleObj.scatter<firstType,types...>::elem;
}

template<typename firstType,typename ...types,int index>
auto getHelper(myTuple<firstType,types...> &tupleObj,IntToType<index>)
-> decltype(getHelper(static_cast<myTuple<types...>&>(tupleObj),IntToType<index-1>()))
{
    return getHelper(static_cast<myTuple<types...>&>(tupleObj),IntToType<index-1>());
}

/* these don't work, the first getHelper function doesn't work as an exit */
//template<typename ...types>
//auto getHelper(myTuple<types...> &tupleObj,IntToType<0>)
//-> decltype((tupleObj.scatter<types...>::elem))
//{
//    return tupleObj.scatter<types...>::elem;
//}
//
//template<typename ...types,int index>
//auto getHelper(myTuple<types...> &tupleObj,IntToType<index>)
//-> decltype(getHelper(tupleObj,IntToType<index-1>()))
//{
//    return getHelper(tupleObj,IntToType<index-1>());
//}

template<int index,typename ...types>
auto get(myTuple<types...> &tupleObj)
    -> decltype(getHelper(tupleObj,IntToType<index>()))
{
    return getHelper(tupleObj,IntToType<index>());
}

int main(){
   myTuple<int,int,float,double> obj;
   get<0>(obj) = 2;
   get<3>(obj) = 3.5;
   std::cout<<get<0>(obj)<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<get<3>(obj)<<std::endl;
}
```

The above code works fine, but when I replace the two `getHelper` function templates with those in the comment, the recursive template (the second `getHelper`) keeps calling itself and the compilation fails.

What is the problem here?

I also tried the following example and it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int>
struct IntToType{};

template<typename ...types>
struct typelist{};

template<typename ...types>
void test(typelist<types...> &t,IntToType<0>){
    std::cout<<"test called with 0"<<std::endl;
}

template<typename ...types,int index>
void test(typelist<types...> &t,IntToType<index>){
    std::cout<<"test called with "<<index<<std::endl;
    test(t,IntToType<index-1>());
}

int main(){
    typelist<int,int,char> obj{};
    test(obj,IntToType<2>());
}
```

so now I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the version that works, let's call it version A, you are removing the first type in each recursive call by doing `static_cast<myTuple<types...>&>(tupleObj)` where `tupleObj` is a `myTuple<firstType,types...>`. So `firstType` is thrown away.

In the version that fails, let's call it version B, you are not removing anything: you directly pass `tupleObj` which contains all the types.

This matters because the **signatures** of your functions contain the types passed to the next recursive call, in the trailing return type (the `-> decltype(...)`). In version A, there is no problem because, at some point, there is no more type left in the parameter pack `types` and when the compiler tries to instantiate `getHelper` with no type left for `firstType`, it fails, stops instantiating things and then resolves the calls. In version B, there is always something in the parameter pack `types`, so the compiler keeps trying to instantiate `getHelper` with the same template arguments except for the index, which decreases each time.

**Template argument deduction takes place before overload resolution.** In version B, even though the overload resolution would pick the correct overload with `IntToType<0>`, it cannot get there because it is stuck in template argument deduction: it tries to instantiate an infinite number of `getHelper` functions.

To convince you of that, in version B, change the main `getHelper` overload to this:

```
template<typename ...types,int index>
auto& getHelper(myTuple<types...> &tupleObj,IntToType<index>)
{
   return getHelper(tupleObj,IntToType<index-1>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7j8Gdxh5s)
Without the trailing return type, the `types...` passed to the next recursive call are no longer part of the signature, and the compiler no longer gets stuck trying to instantiate more and more things. Note that the output is probably not what you expect, and that Clang gives a useful warning about that: this version does not pick the correct element of the tuple. It always picks the first (which is an `int` in this case, hence the conversion warning).

Your other, smaller example with `test` works because the recursion is not part of the signature. Change the main overload to this and you get the same problematic situation:

```
template<typename ...types,int index>
auto test(typelist<types...> &t,IntToType<index>) -> decltype(test(t,IntToType<index-1>())) {
    std::cout<<"test called with "<<index<<std::endl;
    return test(t,IntToType<index-1>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zncd7ME6n)
Note that it does not matter whether the other `test` overload returns a value or not, because again, the compiler does not even get far enough to do overload resolution.

I would personally keep using version A since that works just fine. You can simplify it by removing the trailing return types if you wish:

```
template<typename firstType,typename ...types>
auto& getHelper(myTuple<firstType,types...> &tupleObj,IntToType<0>)
{
    return tupleObj.scatter<firstType,types...>::elem;
}

template<typename firstType,typename ...types,int index>
auto& getHelper(myTuple<firstType,types...> &tupleObj,IntToType<index>)
{
    return getHelper(static_cast<myTuple<types...>&>(tupleObj),IntToType<index-1>());
}

template<int index,typename ...types>
auto& get(myTuple<types...> &tupleObj)
{
    return getHelper(tupleObj,IntToType<index>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9339hY8o3)

If you want to use something like version B, you can change it to remove the first type in each recursive call with a helper function:

```
template<typename firstType, typename ...types>
auto myTupleWithoutFirstType(myTuple<firstType, types...>) -> myTuple<types...>;

template<typename ...types,int index>
auto getHelper(myTuple<types...> &tupleObj,IntToType<index>)
-> decltype(getHelper(static_cast<decltype(myTupleWithoutFirstType(myTuple<types...>{}))&>(tupleObj),IntToType<index-1>()))
{
   return getHelper(static_cast<decltype(myTupleWithoutFirstType(myTuple<types...>{}))&>(tupleObj),IntToType<index-1>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4TWazK66c)